# autoloader class fine tune to be usable in every project

Tags: php, object-oriented, classes

I'm open to any advice to help improve this code for general use.

```
/**
*
* This code was created by Joshua Getner.
* @license http://opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php BSD
* 
*
*/

namespace Blacksmith;

class Autoloader
{

    // an array that maps classnames to there filepaths
    protected static $classes = array();

   /**
    * register your classnames and class paths to the autoloader.
    * keeps the loading quick and accurate.
    * @param string $class
    * @param string $path
    * @return null
    */
    public static function setClassPath($className, $path)
    {
        static::$classes[$className] = str_replace('\\' , '/' , $path);
    }

   /**
    * register an array of classname with paths to the file
    * keeps the loading quick and accurate.
    * @param array $classes
    * @return null
    */
    public static function setClassPaths(array $classes)
    {
        static::$classes = array_merge($classes, static::$classes);
    }

   /**
    * return the path to the classname registered.
    * @param string $class
    * @return string
    */
    public static function getClassPath($className)
    {
        return((isset(static::$classes[$className]) ? 
            static::$classes[$className] : false));
    }

   /**
    * return the array of all the classes registered.
    * @return array
    */
    public static function getClassPaths()
    {
        return static::$classes;
    }

   /**
    * return a formated file path according to the PSR standard
    * @param string $class
    * @return string
    */
    public static function formatPSRClass($class)
    {
        return  str_replace(array('\\', '_'), '/', strtolower($class)) . '.php';
    }   

   /**
    * attempt to load the registered class or interface.
    * @param string $class
    * @return bool
    */
    public static function loadClass($class)
    {
        $path = "";

        // check if the class has been mapped
        if(static::getClassPath($class) !== false)
        {
            // set the path as the mapped path
            $path = static::getClassPath($class);
        }

        // so no class mapped, lets try the PSR way
        else
        {
            // get the path from the class name according to PSR-0
            $path = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)) . '/' . static::formatPSRClass($class);
        }

        // lets attempt to load the file and check if the class or interface exists 
        if(file_exists($path))
        {
            @require $path;

            if(class_exists($class, false) || interface_exists($class , false))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // throw an exception no class was loaded.
        else
        {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf('unable to load the requested class: %s at path %s', $class, $path));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't see a reason to use static methods here, consider using plain 'ol methods.
2. Why throw an exception? PHP will issue a fatal error when a class is used but not defined.
3. Since you are not using `spl_autoload_register()`, I'm not sure yours will play nicely with other autoloaders
4. Why not simply use the [PSR-0 sample autoloader](https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634)?